# proper sytax/ methof for UPDATE mysqli_query()

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

Okay I have this syntax for an UPDATE to a table in mysql inside a php script:

```
   mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE ted SET description=$line[5]
    WHERE speaker='$speaker' AND event='$event'");
```

Is there somehting wrong with it? it runs properly in my scriipt (no error's) however no updates are made even though: it is called multiple times (and has lines which match the WHERE condition) heres  the entire script

```
<?php
$contents = file_get_contents('ted_csv.txt');
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","admin","Media2net");
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM ted");

 $i=0;
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
    $speaker =$row['speaker'];
    $event =$row['event'];
    $pattern2 = preg_quote($speaker, '/');
    $pattern1 = preg_quote($event, '/');
    $pattern1 = "/^.*$pattern1.*\$/m";

    $pattern2 = "/^.*$pattern2.*\$/m";

    if(preg_match_all($pattern1, $contents, $matches)){ 
            $submatch =  implode("\n", $matches[0]);

       if (preg_match_all($pattern2, $submatch, $better)){ 
          echo "got match" .  $i . "\n";
          $line =str_getcsv( $better[0][0] );

          $a_bool = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE ted SET description=$line[5]
           WHERE speaker='$speaker' AND event='$event'");
          if ($a_bool){
             echo "got match" .  $i . "\n";
          }else{
             echo "query unsuccesful for match" .  $i . "\n";
          }

       }
    }

    $i++;
}//end of while loop results
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

As you can see a match should be available as same string's `$speaker and $event` were pulled from table ted

So clearly there's something wrong with my syntax as for each query `$a_bool` is false resulting in  `echo "query unsuccessful for match" .  $i . "\n"` being called for each query . Any explanation of what I have done wrong would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try  `$a_bool = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE ted SET description={$line[5]} WHERE speaker='$speaker' AND event='$event'");` you need to use {} to reference an external array element within a string or yo uneed to drop out of your query eg `description=".$line[5]." AND`

Comment: @Dave no luck with just adding the `{$line[5]}` change

Comment: Don't forget if its a string it also needs to be within single quotes as HP has said below `'{$line[5]}'`

Comment: thank's yes this does work ... what exactly do the curly braces do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SET description=$line[5]`   should be in quotes

like

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE ted SET description='{$line[5]}'
WHERE speaker='$speaker' AND event='$event'");
```

Comment: @Ø Hanky Panky Ø hey this kind of work's about half the time ... what exactly does the '{}' do will adding the same concept to event and speaker (both strings) result in all matching?

Comment: Problem were those quotes, not `{}`. These braces are used if you have to interpolate array values inside quoted strings. For ordinary variables inside double quotes they are not needed

Comment: @Ø Hanky Panky Ø okay I will accept your answer as soon as S.O. allows me to ... is there any reason that every iteration through the while loop should not have a match in the table as values `WHERE` is matching against were pulled from the table?

Comment: It probably shouldn't be doing that now? the way you have set it up it will return false only if the query fails with an error. Error should be gone by now, is it? and do you escape the values so that thee are no extra quotes etc? you should `mysqli_real_escape_string` all those 3 values before running the query

Comment: @Ø Hanky Panky Ø The error persist sometimes (maybe 1 in 3 querries) ... and no I do not escape anything My script is as seen ... but a line where `$speaker= "Rita Pierson" ` and `$event = "TED Talks Education"` fails for some reason

Comment: What is the value of `$contents` ?

Comment: The table was built by scraping data from an html page, and `$contents` has other information for almost each entry that was scraped from the html page and is a csv file containing almost each video from ted.com you can see it here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AsKzpC8gYBmTcGpHbFlILThBSzhmZkRhNm8yYllsWGc&hl=en#gid=0 i downloaded it as a csv file as I thouht it would be easiest way to interact with it